# content_for cannot insert contents into <head>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a certain action in my application, `content_for` does not insert content to `yield` codes in `<head>`, but only for those in `<body>`.

For instance, I have:

```
- content_for :optional_urls do
  www.aaa.bbb
```

When I place the following in `<head>`, `www.aaa.bbb` appears at the top of the `<body>`.

```
= yield :optional_urls
```

But when the `yield` tag is placed within `<body>`, `www.aaa.bbb` gets inserted into the right place. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have the full source for the page by chance? since this is haml it might help due to the indentation specific formatting.

Comment: @Chris It's a very short file (4 lines), and I removed everything but the `content_for` block, and the problem persists.

Comment: I found something interesting. When the `content_for` block contains a string as shown in the question, the problem persists. But if I insert an html element, the it works as intended. I wonder if it's an issue with HAML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to properly structure the plaintext for www.aaa.bbb within that content_for. Below is the suggested way to do plaintext within HAML markup. The lack of the equals sign for your string is what is likely giving you the problems.

```
- content_for :optional_urls do
  = "www.aaa.bbb"
```

You can also use rails tags to accomplish linking javascript resources for page specific javascript if you so wish (as seen below).

```
- content_for :head do
  = javascript_include_tag "google-maps-overlays"
```